# How to convert a Class Library Project to a Web API Project in Visual studio?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a Class Library. I want to convert this to an API project.  I have created a Controller folder and a controller file. Added necessary Nuget packaged and deployed to a webroot. But the api url is giving 404 error. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, for one thing you did not post how the bootstrapping is done. Just adding a nuget package won't magically bring a controller to live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create Controllers folder and add a TestController.cs

  public class TestController : Controller
- Have a method with  [HttpGet] (Optional)

  [HttpGet]
      public bool Index()
      {
          return true;
      }
- App_start/routeconfig.cs should be present

  public class RouteConfig
  {
      public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
          routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  ```
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new
          {
              controller = "{controller}",
              action = "All",
              id = UrlParameter.Optional
          }
      );
  }
  ```

  }
- Global.asax should load routeconfig.cs

  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
- Deploy dlls and folder structure to root.